# Php - trying to insert urls into a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, url, insert

I am simply trying to insert these objects into a table with php.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES( '.$active.' , '.$id.' , '.$time.' , '.$url.' ,"some string" )';
```

The url in the above code is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAYc3gGjYW8

When I leave the url column empty it works, when I put an url in it then it doesnt work and I get the following error.

"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAYc3gGjYW8 ,"some string" )'
 at line 1."

QUESTION:

Why does the url not insert just like a normal string?

Is there some sort of function I need to perform on the url_string before it is accepted by MySQL?

PS - the url column is currently VARCHAR(256).

Any help appreciated guys...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not escaping your inputs. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is your friend.

Remember all input is evil. Validate and sanitize, otherwise you're going to be subject to a whole host of nastiness, from data that's out of bounds (124 char long strings when the field is varchar(10), for example) to opening your code up to SQL injection exploits.

Example:

```
$safe_url = mysqli_real_escape_string($database_connection_object, $url);
```

Also, you might want to save yourself some keystrokes, change that string to a double quoted one and interpolate the variables - i.e. `"blah blah $some_var foo foo"` is the same as `'blah blah ' . $some_var . ' foo foo'`

Answer (score 3):

While I *completely* agree with the `mysql_real_escape_string()` comments, it looks like you forgot to wrap the URL in quotes just like any other string should be.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES( '.$active.' , '.$id.' , '.$time.' , "'.$url.'" ,"some string" )';
```

You can tell by looking at the MySQL error:

```
://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAYc3gGjYW8 ,"some string" )
```

There is no quote at the end of the URL :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your input. Have a look at [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). You might also want to look at a database abstraction layer like [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Assuming you're using the `mysql_*` procedural functions, and after you've connected to the database, your script should look like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES( '.$active.' , '.$id.' , '.$time.' , "'.mysql_real_escape_string($url).'" ,"some string" )';
```

I would also **strongly** recommend escaping the other values as well:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES( "'.mysql_real_escape_string($active).'" , "'.mysql_real_escape_string($id).'" , "'.mysql_real_escape_string($time).'" , "'.mysql_real_escape_string($url).'" ,"some string" )';
```

unless they are SQL expressions or you have previously escaped them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've escaped all of the inputs into the DB using something like `mysql_real_escape_string($string)`. It'll stop you being open to SQL injection attacks and make sure strings are being read correctly.

Answer (score -1):

`$id =  $_GET['id'];$name =  $_GET['name'];$lat =  $_GET['lat'];$long =  $_GET['long']; 
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbname.tablename (`id`,`name`,`lat`,`long`) VALUES      ('".$id."','".$name."','".$lat."','".$long."')");`

Comment: it works just add ('id','name','lat','long') make quotation mark like this;press same time altgr and comma later press space button